# why is my redirect code removing directory?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web

I am trying to redirect some parts of my url but for some reason it is stripping out the directory after redirect... tried many things here is the information below

when i go to this link

```
http://example.com/weddings/peacock-wedding.php
```

it redirects to

```
http://www.example.com/peacock-wedding.php
```

stripping out

```
/weddings/
```

my htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^example.com [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://www.example.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]
```

help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok figured it out!
posting answer in case anyone needs help with it
this goes in htaccess of sub directory in my case in "weddings" directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^(example.com)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/weddings/$1 [R=301,L]
```